# display non-uniform datas with a gauss curve (a bit like kernel density estimation)

Tags: d3.js

I've got this kind of non uniforme datas :

```
[{'time':0,'sum':0},{'time':600,'sum':2},{'time':700,'sum':4},{'time':1200,'sum':1},{'time':1300,'sum':3},{'time':1600,'sum':1},{'time':2000,'sum':0}];
```

"time" is on x axis and "sum" on y axis. If I make an area, I've got these shapes (curved in red, not curved in white) :
https://codepen.io/kilden/pen/podadRW

But the meaning of this is wrong. I have to interpret the "missing" datas. A bit like the "kernel density estimation" charts (example here :https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341954) where values are at zero when there is no data, but there is a "fall off" around the point with data. (a gaussian curve)
It's hard to explain with words (and English is not my mother tongue). So I did this second codepen to show the idea of the shape. The area in red is the shape I want (White one is the reference of the first codepen) :

https://codepen.io/kilden/pen/VwrQrbo

I wonder if there is a way to make this kind of cumulative gaussian curves with a (hidden?) d3 function or a trick function ?

Comment: It kind of looks exactly like a kernel density estimation except that you already did sum up some observations that fall onto the same time. Did you try the linked example? You just have to multiply the kernel by the value of sum.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes, it's the first thing I did. I've tried to adapt the linked example to my needs but this example has a big problem for me : this seems to calculate a percentage of the total points in the interval to calculate the curve (the vertices), whereas I want precise and fixed values if I change the interval. (I've got a dynamic interval with a zoom like this : var x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([startTime,endTime)]).range([0, width]);)

Comment: I don't think this is a question concerning d3 but instead the mathematics behind whatever you are trying to achieve. The kernel density estimate in point x is the mean of all the individual kernels (shifted by the observations and scaled by the bandwidth). You take the mean because you want to estimate a probability density which represents proportions.

Comment: In your case you should just take the sum of all individual kernels an make sure that each individual kernel scales to the fixed observation value (the variable is called "sum" in your example) and choose an appropriate bandwidth. However, this results in just a pretty chart without real value from a mathematical/statistical standpoint.

Comment: You're right : It's just a mathematic problem. I've succeed using these Kernel density fonctions for a bunch of points, but I have always to deal with two vars to  make the curve "right" : a bandwidth and, what I've called a "height factor". So it's ok for one case, but it's not very dynamic. If I add or remove a point, my curve won't be right, becoming too low or too high.

Comment: I worked on this new codepen :  https://codepen.io/kilden/pen/jOaKZNK.
The curve is quite good for what I want. However, if you remove or add some data, it will get worse. How can I change my code to be sure that my curve is "sticked" (tangent) to the points ?

Answer (score 0):

A. Your cheating yourself when you use the Epanechnikov kernel, evaluate these on a rather coarse grid and make a smooth line interpolation so that it looks gaussian. Just take a gaussian kernel to start with.

B. You're comparing apples and oranges. A kernel density estimate is an estimate of a probability density that cannot be compared to the count of observations. The integral of the kernel density estimate is always equal to 1. You can scale the estimate by the total count of observations, but even then your curve would not "stick" to the point, since the kernel spreads the observation away from the point.

C. What comes close to what you want to achieve is implemented below. Use a gaussian curve which is 1 at 0, i. e. without the normalizing factor and the rescaling by the bandwidth. The bandwidth now scales only the width of the curve but not its height. Then use your original data array and add up all these curves with the weight `sum` from your data array.

This will match your data points when there are no clustered observations. Naturally, when two observations are close to each other, their individual gaussian curves can add up to something bigger than each observation.

DISCLAIMER: As I already pointed out in the comments, this just produces a pretty chart and is mathematical nonsense. I strongly recommend working out the mathematics behind what it is you really want to achieve. Only then you should make a chart of your data.

```js
const WIDTH = 600;
const HEIGHT = 150;
const BANDWIDTH = 25;
let data = [
  {time: 0, sum: 0},
  {time: 200, sum: 4},
  {time: 250, sum: 2},
  {time: 500, sum: 1},
  {time: 600, sum: 2},
  {time: 1500, sum: 5},
  {time: 1600, sum: 4},
  {time: 1800, sum: 3},
  {time: 2000, sum: 0},
];

// svg
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", WIDTH)
    .attr("height", HEIGHT)
    .style("background-color", "grey");
// scales
const x_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 2000])
  .range([0, WIDTH]);
const y_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([HEIGHT, 0]);
// curve interpolator
const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => x_scale(d.time))
    .y(d => y_scale(d.sum))
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

const grid = [...Array(2001).keys()];

svg.append("path")
    .style("fill", "rgba(255,255,255,0.4");


// gaussian "kernel"
const gaussian = k => x => Math.exp(-0.5 * x / k * x / k);
// similar to kernel density estimate
function estimate(kernel, grid) {
  return obs => grid.map(x => ({time: x, sum: d3.sum(obs, d => d.sum * kernel(x - d.time))}));
}

function render(data) {
    data = data.sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time);
  // make curve estimate with these kernels
  const curve_estimate = estimate(gaussian(BANDWIDTH), grid)(data);
  // set endpoints to zero for area plot
  curve_estimate[0].sum = 0;
  curve_estimate[curve_estimate.length-1].sum = 0;

    y_scale.domain([0, 1.5 * Math.max(d3.max(data, d => d.sum), d3.max(curve_estimate, d => d.sum))]);

  svg.select("path")
    .attr("d", line(curve_estimate))

  const circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data, d => d.time)
    .join(
        enter => enter.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", "red"),
      update => update.attr("fill", "white")
    )
      .attr("r", 2)
      .attr("cx", d => x_scale(d.time))
      .attr("cy", d => y_scale(d.sum));
}

render(data);

function randomData() {
    data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    data.push({
      time: Math.round(2000 * Math.random()),
      sum: Math.round(10 * Math.random()) + 1,
    });
  }
  render(data);
}

function addData() {
    data.push({
    time: Math.round(2000 * Math.random()),
    sum: Math.round(10 * Math.random()) + 1,
  });
  render(data);
}

d3.select("#random_data").on("click", randomData);
d3.select("#add_data").on("click", addData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button id="random_data">
Random Data
</button>
<button id="add_data">
Add data point
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. Indeed, you’re right ! I was not looking for a right mathematical chart. Rather a good representation of an idea. The Epanechnikov kernel wasn’t necessarly the best solution for me.